# HTML literally print

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have a problem with html tags in a message saved into session flash variable.
I have the next string:

```
const SAVE_SUCCESS_MSG = "El responsable <strong>%name%</strong> fue guardado correctamente.";
```

I replace the "%name%" with a value using `str_replace`:

```
$replaced = str_replace('%name%', $tutor->__toString(), self::SAVE_SUCCESS_MSG);
```

The value is replaced correctly, but the browser show the tags literally.

I print the message with Twig:

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.has('status') %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ app.session.flashbag.get('status')[0] }}">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{ app.session.flashbag.get('message')[0] }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: The browser render "<strong>Foo</strong>".

Comment: Where/how are you echoing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML escaping in Symfony with Twig is enabled by default. You can work around it using the `raw` filter like so:

```
{{ app.session.flashbag.get('message')[0]|raw }}
```

See [Symfony "Creating and using Templates"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html).